# How to find maximum output current of a CMOS inverter?

Tags: mosfet, current, cmos

I'm having trouble finding the calculations to find the maximum current at the output of the inverter.

I managed to find all types of different voltages that are found in the CMOS inverter at each moment, but the currents I did not find.

[image]

Comment: Read up on the "gm" parameter of an FET.  For a specific CMOS inverter IC look for the specifications for IoH and IoL.

Comment: Actual drain current is load dependent.

Comment: There is an exercise where it gives the following data which are kn=50*10^-3, kp=1000*10^-3 VDD=5 and W/L=5. According to the question, I have to find the output voltage and the maximum output current, since it has no load and I can't find the formulas for the maximum current

Comment: So far I haven't had an answer to my question. Could anyone guide me or give me a better way to resolve this issue?